# Updating a List<Point> on componentResized event

Tags: java, swing

I have a JInternalFrame that I draw on with Graphics2D.  Each Graphics2D object is drawn in a location based on a java.util.List.  I am interested in updating the location of the points on a componentResized event and then repaint the Graphics2D objects, in effect scaling with the window, but I cannot figure out how to do it.  I tried overloading the componentResized to get the new window size and add to the points in the list but this isn't working.

EDIT:
After some help (alright a lot of help) from Camickr I figured out how to solve this issue that has been most annoying for several days.  Fixed code is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShapeTransform extends JPanel implements ComponentListener
{
    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    private double scale = 1.0;

    public ShapeTransform()
    {
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 10, 20, 20));
        shapes.add( new Ellipse2D.Double(30, 30, 20, 20) );
        shapes.add( new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 20, 20) );
        shapes.add( new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 70, 20, 20) );

        addComponentListener(this);

            addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                Point p = new Point((int)(e.getX() / scale), (int)(e.getY() / scale));

                for (Shape shape : shapes)
                {
                    if (shape.contains(p))
                    {
                        System.out.println("shape pressed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("no shape pressed");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setColor( Color.BLUE );

        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform(); //
        tx.concatenate( g2d.getTransform() );
        tx.scale(scale, scale);
        g2d.setTransform(tx);

        shapes.forEach(g2d::fill);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShapeTransform");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new ShapeTransform());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {

        scale = ((1.0 - ((300 - getHeight()) * .0035)) + (1.0 - ((300 - getWidth()) * .0035)) / 2);

        System.out.println(scale);
        System.out.println(getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {

    }

    public void setScale(double scale)
    {
        this.scale = scale;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to know at what size the points are at a 1:1 relationship, from there is a simple matter of calculating the difference in the size of the component as a percentage and multiple the points positions by that amount...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I understand the theory behind how to do it, but how do you implement it?

Comment: First you need to define what the size of the internal frame is when the scale is 1.0.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I edited the code in my post.  I added a double for scale and updated the componentResized method to update the scale according the getHeight().  The value of the internaleFrame when scale is 1.0 is determined by setSize(300,300).  Is this what you talking about for the first step?

Comment: From one of your previous postings: `...I will do that for future SSCCE's.` - so much for following the advice. You have NOT posted a SSCCE. All you did was a core dump of your code. Once again all the MouseListener code is irrelevant to the problem. All the internal frame code is irrelevant. `I tried overloading the componentResized to get the new window size and add to the points in the list but this isn't working.`  so where is this code which is relevant. I would expect you just multiply the x/y/width/height values by 2. But without a proper SSCCE I can't test the theory.

Comment: @camickr I took out everything that I thought was not relevant to this post.

Comment: @feltersnach, the point of a SSCCE is to not take out everything but to start with nothing and add it what is relevant. Since we are naturally lazy we will only put back in the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @feltersnach, your scaling calculation doesn't make sense to me. A height below 300 still has a scale greater than one. I would expect you want something like `scale = 1.0 + ((300 - height) * .00165);`. No need for the if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One last answer, unless you start provide a proper `SSCCE` with your question.

The code below is an example of a SSCCE. Only the code needed to demonstrate the problem (or solution) is posted.

If you can't simplify your code then it means you don't understand your question or your problem.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShapeTransform extends JPanel
{
    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    private double scale = 1.0;

    public ShapeTransform()
    {
        shapes.add( new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 10, 20, 20) );
        shapes.add( new Ellipse2D.Double(30, 30, 20, 20) );
        shapes.add( new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 20, 20) );
        shapes.add( new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 70, 20, 20) );

        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                Point p = new Point((int)(e.getX() / scale), (int)(e.getY() / scale));

                for (Shape shape: shapes)
                {
                    if (shape.contains(p))
                    {
                        System.out.println("shape pressed");
                        return;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("no shape pressed");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setColor( Color.BLUE );

        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform(); //
        tx.concatenate( g2d.getTransform() );
        tx.scale(scale, scale);
        g2d.setTransform(tx);

        for (Shape shape : shapes)
        {
            g2d.fill( shape );
        }

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public void setScale(double scale)
    {
        this.scale = scale;
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShapeTransform");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new ShapeTransform());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'll let you add the ComponentListener to the panel so you can dynamically change the scale.

If you can't solve the problem, then you have a proper SSCCE that you can update your question with.

Once you solve the problem and understand the concept, then you fix your real program.

Comment: once again, thanks for helping me.  I am trying to learn and you have been a great help.

Comment: In case you haven't noticed all you need to do is change the scale value to see the custom painting change. First start my doing it manually to prove the concept works. Then add the ComponentListener to automatically change the scale based on your requirements.

Comment: I did notice that by changing it manually.  I am working on making it update on a componentResize event right now.