# AffineTransform: how to scale only one shape Triangle

Tags: java, swing, affinetransform

I have this code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
        window.setVisible(true);


    }
}

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect (10, 10, 100, 100);
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon(new int[] {100, 150, 200}, new int[] {200, 100, 200}, 3);
        g.drawPolygon(triangle);
    }
}
```

It draws this:

[image]

I want to scale only Triangle, so it becomes thrice is big:

[image]

I understand that I need to use `AffiniteTransform`, but I don't understand how.

I only know that I need the scaling instance:

```
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(3, 3);
```

All answers I've seen were very confusing or just used `g2d.setTransform(at)` which doesn't seem to be what I need, seeing as the square is supposed to stay the same size.

**EDIT**: And how do I scale a Triagle, while keeping its leftmost coordinate at the same location? (leftmost (x,y) stays the same)

New code:

```
public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
        window.setVisible(true);


    }
}

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect (10, 10, 100, 100);
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon(new int[] {100, 150, 200}, new int[] {200, 100, 200}, 3);
         AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1.5, 1.5);
        ((Graphics2D) g).setTransform(at);
        g.drawPolygon(triangle);
        ((Graphics2D) g).setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1,1));
validate();

     }
}
```

gives this:

[image]

The triangle shifts as it gets scaled.

Is it possible to keep the triangle at the same spot - that is to keep its leftmost bottom corner at the same spot?

[image]

Comment: Draw the square, **then** set the scaling transform, then draw the triangle..

Comment: Also don't forget to create a separate Graphics objects to do the painting so the transform only affects the painting of the current component. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32292230/131872 for an example of the first approach.